# Weak converge sequence problem in Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a Banach space  $x \in X $.$(x_n)_n \subseteq X$ $$x_n\rightharpoonup x$$ $\exists(y_n)_n \subseteq X \ni y_n$ is a linear combinations of $x_n$ then  $$y_n \rightarrow x$$

Comment: Show effort before close

Comment: I prove $y_n\rightharpoonup x$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%27s_lemma

Comment: Span of $(x_n)$ is convex. For a convex set weak closure equals the norm closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y=Spann\{(x_n)\}$ we will show $ x \in Cl(Y)$. We know $f(t)=inf_{y \in Cl(Y)}||t-y||$ functional element of $ X'$ we known this from Hann-Bannach theorem. Also we know $||f||=1$ and $\forall y \in Y f(y)=0$. $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ then $\forall g \in X'$ $g(x_n)\rightarrow g(x)$ so $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x) $ and this says
$\lim_{n \to \infty} |f(x_n)-f(x)|=0$ then $f(x)=0$ and this means $x\in Cl(Y)$. Finally we get $\exists(y_m) \subseteq Y $ and $y_m \rightarrow x$